# Unexpected response code 500 for my .php/?PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: php, android, mysql, session, android-volley

I am trying to acces my GetUserData.php file to diplay the user info stored in the database onto a profile page in my Android app. I have:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sessionId = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.SID, "SessionID");

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php/?PHPSESSID=" + sessionId,
```

and my session id is getting stored from when the user first logs in. However I am getting the error

BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://............/GetUserData.php/?PHPSESSID=54609c62fec7fc28631d708da687ab55

Here is the rest of the method:

```
    private void getUserData() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sessionId = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.SID, "SessionID");

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php/?PHPSESSID=" + sessionId,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        //json string to jsonobject
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        //get json sstring created in php and store to JSON Array
                        result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.json_array);

                        //get username from json array
                        getUserInfo(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getUserInfo(JSONArray jsonArray){
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            userInfo.add(json.getString(Config.getUsername));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
    getFname.setText(userInfo.indexOf(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable passing of the session id by GET instead of cookies, you might have to activate the `session.use_trans_sid` php.ini option, which is disabled by default (Which means that, by defaut, session id is only passed by cookies -- never by GET).

Comment: I am unable to edit the php.ini file. Is there a way I can enable it during login or something? Something like : `ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", true);` ???

Comment: You can try that, not sure if it will work though. If you can't get it to work try sending a Cookie header in your request. Something like this:
`stringRequest.setHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + sessionId);`

Comment: Where in my method would I add this? As a parameter in StringRequest?

Comment: Above the line that says: `requestQueue.add(stringRequest);`. If it doesn't work, try using HttpGet instead of Google's StringRequest helper.

Comment: I dont think .setHeader is a method. There is a getHeaders? I found this on a website will I have to do something like this?

Comment: `public class CookieRequest extends StringRequest {
        public CookieRequest(String url, String sessid,
                Response.Listener<String> listener,
                Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(Method.GET, url, listener, errorListener);
            
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Cookie", sessid);
            return map;
        }
}`

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at this ... and GetUserData.php/?PHPSESSID=54609c6... looks rather weird why is the / just after the .php ?

Comment: can you help me figure out my problem?